# Nvidia GPU driver on Windows 11 latest release

Tags: gpu, windows-11, graphics, nvidia, nvidia-rtx

Windows 11 version 11.2203.30.0 is installed on my laptop. lately I am confronting some issues like VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE or DCP_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION and ... While I am trying to play a game or video that need my Nvidia GPU. Can anyone explain what's the problem? I have installed the latest version of GPU drivers. Should I wait for new releases?

Comment: Try updating all the other drivers on your laptop (BIOS, and Chipset for sure) but if the manufacturer has a driver update App, use that.  Otherwise wait for the next Nvidia driver release.

Comment: You are running an Insider Preview build of Windows 11.  Unexpected incompatibility with Nvidia or AMD display drivers are always a possibility. I would downgrade to Windows 11 21H2 and see if the incompatibility still exists. Your actually running build 22598 by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound You are right. I have done downgrade and Everything is ok!